# How to change the ViewPager page on Completion of a track in MusicPlayer activity?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, audio-player, android-music-player

There are 3 activities.

1. Introduction activity
2. ViewPager activity (swipeable pager)
3. MusicPlayer activity

I want to change the ViewPager page when MusicPlayer changes the track.

***For eg.***

MusicPlayer is playing track No. 1 in the background.
Page No. 1 is loaded in the ViewPager.

Now on completion of Track 1.. MusicPlayer plays Track 2 (in the background)
So at this time, Page No. 2 should be loaded in ViewPager.

When I am putting this on track change event -> pager.setCurrentItem(track)

the application is crashing.

Comment: **application is crashing** what is this error you are getting?

Comment: share some code

Comment: Actally my laptop do not support virtualization so I everytime I had to test the application by creating apk and transferring it to my mobile. So dont know whats the error. And my mobile do not support usb debugging. its redmi note 5